# Cannot register HttpRequestHandlerServlet with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to use HttpRequestHandlerServlet in common with HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway to expose simple REST URL to browser. But I cannot register HttpRequestHandlerServlet, I'm doing it in the following way:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean inboundServletRegistration(ApplicationContext context) {
    final HttpRequestHandlerServlet servlet = new HttpRequestHandlerServlet();
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
            servlet, "/demo/*");
    registration.setName("inboundServletRegistration");

    return registration;
}
```

Spring boot application start's ok, but when try to access HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway endpoint with mapping:

```
@Bean
public HttpRequestHandler httpInboundEndPoint() {
    // Http Rest gateway expecting reply.
    final HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway restGateway = new
            HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway(true);

    // Mapping of URL this gateway consumes...
    restGateway.setRequestMapping(
            mapping(new HttpMethod[]{HttpMethod.GET}, "/context/{param}"));
```

at address http://localhost:8080/demo/context/{param} I get total nonsense crash:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException:
```

Bean named 'inboundServletRegistration' must be of type [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestHandler], but was actually of type [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean]

Did you come across to this problem? Can you please help me out?

Comment: Anyone? I'm kind of thinking whether this can actually work...Because after look into the source code of HttpRequestHandlerServlet...It seems that the problem is in the fact that the servlet-name of HttpRequestHandlerServlet doesn't match with the name of HttpRequestHandler (HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway in my case)....Is somehow possible to set the name of HttpRequestHandlerServlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

Key to pass this problem is to register HttpRequestHandler under the same bean name as the HttpRequestHandlerServlet registration bean...Going rather back to XML config...:-(